# Spring boot with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I have a model class at path :
`com.test.MyDto`

Model :

```
name
email
```

I have stored the value in the MongoDb. Now my DB will be like this

```
name : abc
email : abc@gmail.com
_class : com.test.MyDto
```

Everything is working fine, but now I decided to update the package name `com.spring.test.MyDto`

After updating the package name, all the older records were failing in casting. How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just doing a blanket update of your collection to the `_class` field:

```
db.your_dto.update(
    { },
    { $set: { "_class": "com.spring.test.MyDto" } }
);
```

You should shutdown your Spring application, then run the above update.  Finally, restart the Spring application with the new package name.

Comment: So whenever we are refactoring/renaming the classes we should do DB update before deploying it on production?

Comment: Maybe Spring has some migration tool or script which can help automate this, I don't know.  AFAIK, to Mongo the `_class` field is just any other text field.